# Understanding the spec of the ogg header format

Tags: audio, hex, ogg, opus

For writing my own ogg-container-class (not using libogg), I try to understand the needed header format. According to the [spec](https://xiph.org/vorbis/doc/framing.html), at byte 27 of the stream (starting to count at 0) starts the "segment_table (containing packet lacing values)". This is the red marked byte `13`. Concerning the Opus-data that I want to include, the Opus data [must](https://wiki.xiph.org/OggOpus) start with `OpusHead (4F 70 75 73)` on its beginning. Why doesn't it start on position 27 where the red `13` is placed? A `13` is a "device control 3" symbol that neither occurs in the Ogg spec, nor in the Opus spec.

EDIT: I found [this link](http://www.file-recovery.com/ogg-signature-format.htm) that describes the spec a little. There it becomes clear (which it is not from the first link imho) that the `13` (byte 27) is the size of the following segment.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That appears to be a single byte giving the length of the following segment_table data. So there is 13(hex) bytes (16 decimal) bytes of segment_table data.

Comment: Is your answer based on reading the spec? Because the spec says that byte 26 should be the `"page_segments", "The number of segment entries to appear in the segment table.[...]"`. So why would this now be byte 27?

Comment: Yes, I read the spec which is not very clear. I read it as saying this byte is the length.

Comment: How? It says: "Byte 26: page_segments". Why do you think it should be byte 27? They start counting at 0.

Comment: I found a link that explains the spec a bit more detailed. You are right, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 3533](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3533.html#section-6) is a more verbose description of the format header.

Byte 26 says how many bytes the segment table occupies, so you read that, add 27, and that tells you where the first packet starts (or continues).

The segment table tells you the length(s) of the encapsulated packet(s). Basically you read through the table, adding together the values in each successive byte. If the value you just added is < 255 then that marks a packet boundary, so record the current value of the accumulator, reset it to zero, then continue until you reach the end of the table.

In your example, the segment table size in byte 26 is 1, so the data starts at 27+1 or byte 28, which is the start of the 'OpusHead' string. The value in the 1 byte segment table is 0x13, so the packet is 19 bytes long. 28+19 is 47 (or 0x2f) which is the start of the 'OggS' capture pattern at the start of the next header.

This slightly complicated algorithm is designed to store framing data for many small packets with bounded overhead while still allowing arbitrarily large packets. Note also that packets can be continued between pages, spanning 2 or more segment tables.